# How to hide the Metro searchPane with Javascript

Tags: javascript, microsoft-metro

Is it possible to hide the Microsoft searchPane with javascript from my application? If yes, then how?

As far as I can see from the docs, it is only possible to open (show) the searchPane. But there is a visibilitychange-event and a boolean (read-only..) visible-field. As I am in strict-mode, it will not be an option to change this.

Code to get the searchPane:

```
var searchPane = Windows.ApplicationModel.Search.SearchPane.getForCurrentView();
searchPane.show(); ** Opens searchPane, yay! **
// searchPane.hide(); ** Exception, not implemented by Microsoft yet.. :( **
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft provides no means of programmatically hiding the search pane. This is by design in order to make sure that all apps provide the same user experience with regards to search.

Comment: Try calling the show method that takes a string parameter and pass an empty string.

Comment: I think I tried this. Unfortunately that worked only if search charm was not opened before.